# How to validate Radio button for gender in android?

Tags: android

Hello Everybody
       How do I get validate my form specially for "gender", where I have used **RadioButton**, so that when **"male"** is selected **"female"** will automatically get unselected. Again for that will I have to take **RadioButton** or it'll be better  to take **RadioGroup**?
                    Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put your gender `RadioButton`s inside a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use RadioGroup.
You can see the full documentation [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

You can refer Example from developer.android.com -> http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons

For Example in your xml file :

```
 <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gender_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <RadioButton android:text="Male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:text="Female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's from the official documentation - [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html#HandlingEvents)

Answer (score 0):

Please Do this -

// Validate the gender selection
if (!maleRadioButton.isChecked && !femaleRadioButton.isChecked) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Please select your gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
return
}

For Better Understanding, you can also go through my project link-
https://github.com/anandrex5/RecyclerView_FlashScreen_Intent_ShowData_into_AnotherActivity_FormValidation_FinalProject

You have to see only ThirdActvity.

Comment: This code is already in Kotlin